# How do I pass in the string from a text file into my JUnit code ?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following file, which contains a binary representation of an `.MSG` file :

binaryMessage.txt

And I put it in my Eclipse workspace, in the following folder - `src/main/resources/test` :

[image]

I want to use the string which is within this text file , within the following JUnit code, so I tried the following way :

```
    request.setContent("src/main/resources/test/binaryMessage");
    mockMvc.perform(post(EmailController.PATH__METADATA_EXTRACTION_OPERATION)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(json(request)))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there  a way I can pass in the string the file directly without using IO code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't read a file without using IO code (or libraries that use IO code). That said, it's not that difficult to read the file into memory so you can send it.

To read a binary file into a `byte[]` you can use this method:

```
private byte[] readToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
request.setContent(readToByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test/binaryMessage")));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment on Samuel's answer, I just noticed that you depend on your concrete execution directory. I personally don't like that and normally use the class loader's functions to find resources.

Thus, to be independent of your working directory, you can use

```
getClass().getResource("/test/binaryMessage")
```

Convert this to URI and Path, then use Files.readAllBytes to fetch the contents:

```
Path resourcePath = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/test/binaryMessage").toURI());
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(resourcePath);
```

... or even roll that into a single expression.

But to get back to your original question: no, this is I/O code, and you need it. But since the dawn of Java 7 (in 2011!) this does not need to be painful anymore.